# Running power to a sub panel for a shed

Tags: electrical, concrete, subpanel, pvc, shed

So a friend of mine wants power to his shed for a tv, a small portable ac unit and some lights. I told him a 60 amp sub panel would be best just in case of expansion. So the issue is that from the panel to the shed is a concrete patio a good bit of the way and he doesn’t want to chop it up to put pvc underground. So my question is can i run schedule 80 pvc exposed from the panel to the sheds sub panel. This conduit is running along a fence line from the panel to the shed out of physical damage. Is this legal to do or is there another way?

Comment: I take it there's a fence on this fenceline, no?  Also, how is the conduit run going to get from the box to the fenceline?